# How to show image view to right side of alert title?

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I want to show image view next to alert view title. for this I have added below code, But my problem is that it is showing too much space between alert title and image view.

```
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Delete", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "TextColor")!])

    let attributedMessageString = NSAttributedString(string: "Should the set heating time really be deleted?", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "TextColor")!])

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "",  preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alert.setValue(attributedMessageString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abort", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) in
        self.startTimeTextField.text = "--:--"
    }))
    
    let imgTitle = UIImage(named:"ArrowUpImage")
    let imgViewTitle = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: alert.view.center.x , y: 15, width: 30, height: 30))
    imgViewTitle.image = imgTitle

    alert.view.addSubview(imgViewTitle)

    let subview = (alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView
    subview.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "BackgroundColor")
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor(named: "SpecialColor")
    self.viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want my alert view looks like below image(alert view title and image view between space is only 10).

[image]

Can you please help me?

Comment: I wouldn't mess with `UIAlertController` as stated in the doc: `The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSTextAttachment -

```
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
let imageOffsetY: CGFloat = -(imageAttachment.image!.size.height/4)
imageAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: imageOffsetY, width: imageAttachment.image!.size.width, height: imageAttachment.image!.size.height)
let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Delete ")
attributedString.append(attachmentString)
alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

Comment: Can we center horizontally to image attachment with alert title?